# QGIS Calculate Field with Function Editor invalid expression

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, field-calculator, string, qgis-custom-function

I have some data which is built like this:

```
a,bbb,ccc
```

where bbb and ccc vary in length.

I want to extract the last segment of the string, after the second ",".
Using the Function Editor:

```
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def sp_split(value1):
    return value1.split(",")[2]
```

I save it as a function called `sp_split`, but when I call it in the expression with a field for a value, it doesn't recognize it.
[image]

Pressing More Info gives me this explanation:

```
Eval Error:
sp_split() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)
```

What might be the reason for that? I'm at a loss here.
I'm using the function because of the split, if there is another way of using the built-in expression to retain the "ccc" part, I'll gladly use it.

Comment: I don't have access to QGIS now, but check for the regular expressions functions. You need to match something like: .*,.*,(.*)

Comment: Click on (more info) it will tell you what is wrong.

Comment: @NathanW Updated the question, Eval Error:
sp_split() takes exactly 1 argument (3 given)

Comment: Make it this `sp_split(value1, feature, parent)`

Comment: @NathanW Looks like I'm back to square one, now error reads 'QgsExpressionFunction' object has no attribute 'split'. Which is weird, as typing the function does give me "split" in the autocomplete suggestion

Comment: What QGIS version?

Comment: @NathanW 2.14.1, OSGeo4W

Comment: Maybe the value1 is not being read as string, do `str(value1).split` and try again.

Comment: As @AlexandreNeto suggested you can use `regexp_substr( "species_la", ',.*,(.*)')` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you need to add `from qgis.utils import qgsfunction` into your code. You can also remove the other imports as they're not necessary. So something like this should work:

```
from qgis.utils import qgsfunction

@qgsfunction(args="auto", group='Custom')
def sp_split(value1, feature, parent):
    return value1.split(",")[2]
```

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: @HDunn - Awesome, glad it worked =)

Comment: Also, caiohamamura method worked as well, except that some of the text values concatenations had only one "," in between the parts. So I was planning on just calling it up using [-1].